# Copy specific cells of same row in another worksheet if text found

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy specific cells of a row, to another worksheet in same bock, if determined Text appears in a "H" column. I´m alredy able to copy the entire column, but I´m not able to copy just the cells of the row I really want.

```
Dim rango As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sumas y Saldos")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Check")

nfil = Source.Range("H9").End(xlDown).Row
i = 9
For Each rango In Source.Range("H8:H" & nfil)
    If rango = "REVISAR" Then
       Source.Rows(rango.Row).Copy Target.Rows(i)
       i = i + 1
    End If
Next rango
'2 second try of the code, this is what I try to do in the If to copy just that cells.
If rango = "REVISAR" Then
Source.Rows(rango.Column).Copy Target.Column(i)
Source.Range("G9:G" & nfil).Copy Destination:=Target.Range("A8:A" & nfil)
Source.Range("H9:H" & nfil).Copy Destination:=Target.Range("B8:B" & nfil)
Source.Range("I9:I" & nfil).Copy Destination:=Target.Range("C8:C" & nfil)
Source.Range("J9:J" & nfil).Copy Destination:=Target.Range("D8:D" & nfil)
Source.Range("K9:K" & nfil).Copy Destination:=Target.Range("E8:E" & nfil)
Source.Rows(rango.Row).Copy Target.Rows(i)
i = i + 1
End If
```

Hope someone can help me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()` method of `Range` object, like follows (not tested, explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Check")

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sumas y Saldos")
        With .Range("G8:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row) 'reference its columns G:K cells from row 8 down to last not empty one in column "H"
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="REVISAR" ' filter referenced cells on 2nd column "REVISAR" content
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(2)) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Target.Range("A8:D8")              ' if any filtered cell then get their underlying cells
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It does not worked for me, I didnt get anything on the target.. I will try to modify it, thanks

Comment: While in VBA IDE, step through the code by pressing F8 while placing the cursor in any statement of the code. At any step you can check in the Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) the values of any relevant variable by typing `?not_object_variable_name` or `?object_variable_name.property` (e.g.: `ActiveWorkbook.Name` or the likes) and see if it fits expectation. You can also switch between VBA IDE and Excel UI to see what's happening in relevant sheets/ranges

Comment: Im new in VBA, so im not able to get what I want doing this, I cant understand it.. Sorry and thanks anyway